# A bug in short c++ code, and I think it's due to the deconstruct function of class. But I cannot find

Tags: c++

I think the bug is related to the delete dynamic array manipulation. But I'm not sure in detail.

I'm now studying c++ myself, so I'm a totally freshhand. This is a small exercise from a book and I'm trying to solve it. The "main()" function part is what it originally is so I'm only allowed to code about the class "Array2"

Thanks in advance!

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstring>
    using namespace std;
    class Array2
    {
        int row, col;
        int **a;
    public:
        Array2(int s1=1, int s2=1) 
        {
            row = s1;
            col = s2;
            a = new int *[row];
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            {
                a[i] = new int[col];
            }
        };
        Array2(Array2 & b)
        {
            a = b.a;
        }
        ~Array2()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            {   
                    delete[] a[i];
            }

            delete[] a;
        }
        int * operator [] (int i)
        {
            return a[i];
        }
        int operator () (int s1, int s2)
        {
            return a[s1][s2];
        }

    };
    int main() {
        Array2 a(3, 4);
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                a[i][j] = i * 4 + j;
        for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                cout << a(i, j) << ",";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << "next" << endl;
        Array2 b; b = a;
        for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                cout << b[i][j] << ",";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }**
```

Comment: Your copy constructor is wrong. It causes the same memory to be `delete`d multiple times.

Comment: Also this is the first time I see someone call a destructor a deconstructor, but it sounds cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the assignment in this code snippet.

```
Array2 b; b = a;
          ^^^^^
```

You did not define the copy assignment operator. So the compiler define it implicitly in the similar way as you defined incorrectly yourself the copy constructor.

```
    Array2(Array2 & b)
    {
        a = b.a;
    }
```

You have to make a deep copy of objects during construction using the copy constructor or during assignment using the copy assignment operator.

Otherwise several pointers point to the same memory that will be deleted at least twice.

Answer (score 1):

Your copy constructor is incorrect. You cannot just copy the address of the internal storage, otherwise you'll end up freeing it twice.